# Python Pandas - Remove a word from a cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have column containing names. I want to remove the name and the ; where its marked as (Retired) or (retired) after the name. But the problem is, it does not appear in the same format. Sometimes the cell has multiple names and one name is retried. In another case the cell will have first name followed by retired then the last name.

Dataframe = df

> Sample column values - Current state

```
Owner Name
George (Georgy) (Retired) Clooney
Meghan (retired) Markle
Harry Porter (Retired)
Hermione Granger; Harry Porter (Retired)
Ginny Weasley; Ron Weasley; Harry Porter (retired); Luna Lovegood
```

> Sample column values - Future state

```
Owner Name
Null
Null
Null
Hermione Granger
Ginny Weasley; Ron Weasley; Luna Lovegood
```

I thought of using replace with "" but it does not work. Please. I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: do you want to remove the row if it has (retired) or just removed the retired string from it?

Comment: Sorry i missed your comment. If I wanted to remove, I will use contains 'retired| Retired' and use a drop function. But I want to keep the row and only remove the name if its retired. Below solutions worked for me. But I appreciate you making time to add a comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), filter, join again with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['Owner Name'] = (df['Owner Name']
 .str.split(';\s*', expand=True).stack()
 .loc[lambda s: ~s.str.contains('\(Retired\)', case=False)]
 .groupby(level=0).agg('; '.join)
)
```

Output:

```
                                  Owner Name
0                                        NaN
1                                        NaN
2                                        NaN
3                           Hermione Granger
4  Ginny Weasley; Ron Weasley; Luna Lovegood
```

Comment: OMG! Worked. What's the purpose of s*'? and ~s. Thanks a million

Comment: `\s*` is to match optional spaces after the comma, `~` is the boolean NOT to get rows that do not match "(retired)"

Answer (score 2):

With single regex replacement:

```
df['Owner Name'] = df['Owner Name'].str.replace(r'[^;]*\(retired\)[^;]*;?', "", regex=True, case=False)\
    .str.strip(';').replace("", np.nan)
```

---

```
                                  Owner Name
0                                        NaN
1                                        NaN
2                                        NaN
3                           Hermione Granger
4  Ginny Weasley; Ron Weasley; Luna Lovegood
```

---

Time execution comparison (just for the case):

```
In [364]: %timeit df['Owner Name'].str.replace(r'[^;]*\(retired\)[^;]*;?', "", regex=True, case=False).str.strip(';'
     ...: ).replace("", np.nan)
322 µs ± 1.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [365]: %timeit df['Owner Name'].str.split(';\s*', expand=True).stack().loc[lambda s: ~s.str.contains('\(Retired\)
     ...: ', case=False)].groupby(level=0).agg('; '.join)
1.19 ms ± 8.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am always confused with regex. How do determine : as first then retired then ; again because that format is not same for all cells. Actually your code worked too. You guys are genius.